Windowless Bedroom Ideas
Weird Room Situation
Hey all.
TL;DR at the top!:
My house is a non-Euclidian nightmare and I need a suggestion for a windowless guest room.
The long part:
So, two years ago I bought a house, and it's a frankenhouse. Built in the 1930s with a dormer and stairs, and a laundry room added later. (Very clearly some kind of DIY or hack job).
The house was a manageable price because of its "quirks".
The crux of my current issue is this:
When the upstairs got added, the stairwell was just sort of tacked onto the back of the house. In doing so, it blocked both windows for one of the bedrooms (now the guest room).
So that bedroom has no secondary fire/emergency exit.
It passed inspection in my area because houses built before 1930 were grandfathered in under the wire (a technicality, really) so legally we're not in trouble. But now my guest room has zero windows and one door, and that just feels unsafe if the worst should happen.
My original suggestion was to cut a new, big-enough-to-exit-through window in the corner of the wall that is now under the staircase. So, like, adding a weird under-the-stairs shaped window in the bottom right corner of that wall... but that just doesn't seem right. Especially because the back fence of our property would be within a foot of the door. Our house is very far back against the back edge of our property line.
The only other thing I can think of to do is to add a second actual door (maybe a pocket door?) to the room on another wall, to let it out into a different part of the house... but I don't know if that's also too weird. Also the room is SMALL, maybe 8x10 or 8x12 feet, at most, so a door eating into the wall space would be rough.
...Any ideas?

Just saw some store selling secret bookcase doors, so a door with shelving.

My reaction would be to make that room something other than a bedroom, so dual escape routes are not, technically, required.

it's kind of hard to imagine.  would sliding windows that allow access onto or below the staircase work?

@keshlam   Some questions on here seem to imply a sofa in an office might give some inspectors willies about a second egress needed.  So being able to sleep comfortably in the room, might be more important than calling it a bedroom or something else.

Pictures of the staircase and location(outside) of the room might help.  There are fire escape rope ladders for higher rooms, since under a staircase is usually not that helpful.

Local authority having jurisdiction, as always. Ask your inspectors what can be done with the room and/or what needs to be done. They might be reasonable. Easier than trying to guess what would pass.

Without pics of the situation, any advice we could give would be worth less than you paid for it.
